# I have a Array of links in list view how I can open these links in one webview

Tags: android, webview

how I can open these all links in one webview if I click first item then it should open first link and so in in one webview .  How I can open these all links in one webview if I click first item then it should open first link and so in in one webview .  How I can open these all links in one webview if I click first item then it should open first link and so in in one webview.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class List_item extends Activity{

    ListView list;
    String[] uniname ={

            "Government College University, Lahore",
            "Lahore College for Women University, Lahore",
            "National College of Arts, Lahore",
            "National School of Public Policy, Lahore",
            "University of Education, Lahore",
            "University of Engineering & Technology, Lahore",
            "University of Health Sciences, Lahore",
            "University of the Punjab, Lahore",
            "University of Veterinary and Animal Sciences, Lahore",
            "National University of Computer and Emerging Sciences(FAST)",
                    " Private Sector Universities/Degree Awarding Institutes",
            "Beaconhouse National University, Lahore",
            "Forman Christian College, Lahore",
            "Hajvery University, Lahore",
            "Imperial College of Business Studies, Lahore",
            "Institute of Management Sciences, Lahore",
            "Lahore School of Economics, Lahore",
            "Lahore University of Management Sciences, Lahore",
            "Minhaj University, Lahore",
            "National College of Buisness Administration& Economics (NCBA&E), Lahore",
            "The Superior University, Lahore",
            "COMSATS Institute of Information Technology (CIIT) - Lahore ", 
            "University of Central Punjab, Lahore",
            "University of Lahore",
            "University of Management And Technology, Lahore",
            "University of South Asia, Lahore"

        };
String[] addres ={

        "GC University, Katchery Road Lahore 54000 ",
        "Near Wapda Flats, Jail Road, Lahore 54000",
        "Shahrah-e-Qauid-e-Azam, 4 Mall Rd, Lahore 54000",
        "Shahrah-e-Quaid-e-Azam, Upper Mall, Lahore.",
        "College Road, Lahore",
        " G.T. Rd, Lahore 54890",
        "Khayaban-e-Jamia Punjab, Lahore 54000",
        "QUAID-E-AZAM CAMPUS:Canal Bank Road, Lahore.",
        "Shaykh Abdul Qadir Jilani Rd, Lahore 54000",
        "Block-B, Faisal Town,Lahore",
        "",
        "Tarogil Campus, 13 Km Raiwind Road، Lahore 54400",
        "Zahoor Elahi Rd, Lahore 54600",
        " 43-52 Industrial Area,, Gurumangat Road, Lahore 54400",
        "Shahkam Industries Rd, Lahore",
        "23، Lahore 54660",
        "Barki Rd, Lahore 54000",
        " Opposite Sector U, DHA., Lahore 54792",
        "Shah Jalani Road, Lahore",
        "178-, A-Block, Lahore",
        "17km Raiwind Rd, Lahore",
        "1.5 KM off Raiwind Rd,Near Labors Colony Defence Rd 54000, Ali Akbar Rd, Lahore",
        "Khayaban-e-Jinnah Lahore",
        "Lahore 54000",
        "University of Management and Technology Rd, Lahore 54000",
        "47 Tufail Rd, Lahore"

        };

    Integer[] imgid={
            R.drawable.im1,
            R.drawable.im2,
            R.drawable.im3,
            R.drawable.im4,
            R.drawable.im5,
            R.drawable.im6,
            R.drawable.im7,
            R.drawable.im8,
            R.drawable.im9,
            R.drawable.im,
            R.drawable.white,
            R.drawable.im10,
            R.drawable.im11,
            R.drawable.im12,
            R.drawable.im13,
            R.drawable.im14,
            R.drawable.im15,
            R.drawable.im16,
            R.drawable.im17,
            R.drawable.im18,
            R.drawable.im19,
            R.drawable.im20,
            R.drawable.im21,
            R.drawable.im22,
            R.drawable.im23,
            R.drawable.im24,


    };
    String[] urlarray={

               " http://www.gcu.edu.pk/",
                "http://www.lcwu.edu.pk/ ",
                "http://www.nca.edu.pk/" ,
                "http://www.nspp.gov.pk ",
                "http://ue.edu.pk/beta/ ",
                "http://www.uet.edu.pk/",
                "http://www.uhs.edu.pk/" ,
                "http://www.pu.edu.pk/ ",
                "http://www.uvas.edu.pk/index.php ",
                "http://www.nu.edu.pk ",
                "http://www.bnu.edu.pk/bnu/ ",
                "http://fccollege.edu.pk/ ",
                "http://www.hajvery.edu.pk/", 
                "http://www.imperial.edu.pk/", 
                "http://site.pakaims.edu.pk/ ",
                "http://www.lahoreschoolofeconomics.edu.pk/ ",
                "https://lums.edu.pk/ ",
                "http://www.mul.edu.pk/ ",
                "http://www.ncbae.edu.pk/",
                "http://www.superior.edu.pk/ ",
                "http://lahore.comsats.edu.pk/ ",
                "http://www.ucp.edu.pk/",
                "http://www.uol.edu.pk/campuses/lahorecampus ",
                "http://umt.edu.pk/index.htm ",
                "http://www.usa.edu.pk/ "

    };
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_view);

        CustomListAdapter adapter=new CustomListAdapter(this, uniname, imgid,addres);
        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //String Slecteditem= uniname[+position];
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Slecteditem, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                view.setSelected(true); 
                Intent i = new Intent(List_item.this, Listwebview.class); 

                i.putExtra("urlx",urlarray[+position]);
                 startActivity(i);      

            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Does Listwebview have the webview and you want the passed link to open there ?

Comment: yes i have listwebview activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open webview inside an alertdialog.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class List_item extends Activity{

    ListView list;
    String[] uniname ={

            "Government College University, Lahore",
            "Lahore College for Women University, Lahore",
            "National College of Arts, Lahore",
            "National School of Public Policy, Lahore",
            "University of Education, Lahore",
            "University of Engineering & Technology, Lahore",
            "University of Health Sciences, Lahore",
            "University of the Punjab, Lahore",
            "University of Veterinary and Animal Sciences, Lahore",
            "National University of Computer and Emerging Sciences(FAST)",
                    " Private Sector Universities/Degree Awarding Institutes",
            "Beaconhouse National University, Lahore",
            "Forman Christian College, Lahore",
            "Hajvery University, Lahore",
            "Imperial College of Business Studies, Lahore",
            "Institute of Management Sciences, Lahore",
            "Lahore School of Economics, Lahore",
            "Lahore University of Management Sciences, Lahore",
            "Minhaj University, Lahore",
            "National College of Buisness Administration& Economics (NCBA&E), Lahore",
            "The Superior University, Lahore",
            "COMSATS Institute of Information Technology (CIIT) - Lahore ", 
            "University of Central Punjab, Lahore",
            "University of Lahore",
            "University of Management And Technology, Lahore",
            "University of South Asia, Lahore"

        };
String[] addres ={

        "GC University, Katchery Road Lahore 54000 ",
        "Near Wapda Flats, Jail Road, Lahore 54000",
        "Shahrah-e-Qauid-e-Azam, 4 Mall Rd, Lahore 54000",
        "Shahrah-e-Quaid-e-Azam, Upper Mall, Lahore.",
        "College Road, Lahore",
        " G.T. Rd, Lahore 54890",
        "Khayaban-e-Jamia Punjab, Lahore 54000",
        "QUAID-E-AZAM CAMPUS:Canal Bank Road, Lahore.",
        "Shaykh Abdul Qadir Jilani Rd, Lahore 54000",
        "Block-B, Faisal Town,Lahore",
        "",
        "Tarogil Campus, 13 Km Raiwind Road، Lahore 54400",
        "Zahoor Elahi Rd, Lahore 54600",
        " 43-52 Industrial Area,, Gurumangat Road, Lahore 54400",
        "Shahkam Industries Rd, Lahore",
        "23، Lahore 54660",
        "Barki Rd, Lahore 54000",
        " Opposite Sector U, DHA., Lahore 54792",
        "Shah Jalani Road, Lahore",
        "178-, A-Block, Lahore",
        "17km Raiwind Rd, Lahore",
        "1.5 KM off Raiwind Rd,Near Labors Colony Defence Rd 54000, Ali Akbar Rd, Lahore",
        "Khayaban-e-Jinnah Lahore",
        "Lahore 54000",
        "University of Management and Technology Rd, Lahore 54000",
        "47 Tufail Rd, Lahore"

        };

    Integer[] imgid={
            R.drawable.im1,
            R.drawable.im2,
            R.drawable.im3,
            R.drawable.im4,
            R.drawable.im5,
            R.drawable.im6,
            R.drawable.im7,
            R.drawable.im8,
            R.drawable.im9,
            R.drawable.im,
            R.drawable.white,
            R.drawable.im10,
            R.drawable.im11,
            R.drawable.im12,
            R.drawable.im13,
            R.drawable.im14,
            R.drawable.im15,
            R.drawable.im16,
            R.drawable.im17,
            R.drawable.im18,
            R.drawable.im19,
            R.drawable.im20,
            R.drawable.im21,
            R.drawable.im22,
            R.drawable.im23,
            R.drawable.im24,


    };
    String[] urlarray={

               " http://www.gcu.edu.pk/",
                "http://www.lcwu.edu.pk/ ",
                "http://www.nca.edu.pk/" ,
                "http://www.nspp.gov.pk ",
                "http://ue.edu.pk/beta/ ",
                "http://www.uet.edu.pk/",
                "http://www.uhs.edu.pk/" ,
                "http://www.pu.edu.pk/ ",
                "http://www.uvas.edu.pk/index.php ",
                "http://www.nu.edu.pk ",
                "http://www.bnu.edu.pk/bnu/ ",
                "http://fccollege.edu.pk/ ",
                "http://www.hajvery.edu.pk/", 
                "http://www.imperial.edu.pk/", 
                "http://site.pakaims.edu.pk/ ",
                "http://www.lahoreschoolofeconomics.edu.pk/ ",
                "https://lums.edu.pk/ ",
                "http://www.mul.edu.pk/ ",
                "http://www.ncbae.edu.pk/",
                "http://www.superior.edu.pk/ ",
                "http://lahore.comsats.edu.pk/ ",
                "http://www.ucp.edu.pk/",
                "http://www.uol.edu.pk/campuses/lahorecampus ",
                "http://umt.edu.pk/index.htm ",
                "http://www.usa.edu.pk/ "

    };
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_view);

        CustomListAdapter adapter=new CustomListAdapter(this, uniname, imgid,addres);
        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //String Slecteditem= uniname[+position];
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Slecteditem, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                view.setSelected(true); 
                Intent i = new Intent(List_item.this, Listwebview.class); 

                //i.putExtra("urlx",urlarray[+position]);
                // startActivity(i);    

                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this); 
                alert.setTitle("Title here");

                WebView wv = new WebView(this);
                wv.loadUrl(urlarray[+position]);
                wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                        view.loadUrl(url);

                        return true;
                    }
                });

                alert.setView(wv);
                alert.setNegativeButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                alert.show();  

            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: The constructor WebView(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){}) is undefined

Comment: the constructor AlertDialog.Builder(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){}) is undefined

Comment: `AlertDialog.Builder alert= new AlertDialog.Builder(List_itemList_item.this);`   use this

Comment: The constructor WebView(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){}) is undefined

Comment: i have a seprate webview activity all i want is list_view activity send array of links to webview activity then after clicking eact item of list view it should open that link(website) within same webview

Comment: `WebView wv = new WebView(getApplicationContext());`

Comment: If you want to display your web view in Second activity. Then use `Intent` and pass your url. In, Second activity page get that link and load a webview. That's all. Don't forget to add `WebView` in respective xml file of  Second page. Loading webview in alertdialog is different from loading a web view directly from activity.

Comment: well its working fine but it only opens the first link remaining only shows the "title here" and "close" nothing else

Comment: I recommend for user convenience, you can load `WebView` in alertdialog.Because, you going to show list of links.  You can maximize the size of webview.

Comment: mm make sure you passing links correctly. you can get rid of title of  alertdialog. I thinks problem is here `wv.loadUrl(urlarray[+position]);` work on it.

Comment: WOW its working better than i want  thank great help

Comment: i dont know this is professional or according to rule of this site but i have more questions about my project could you help?

Comment: According to rule is NOT. You have to do on your own. But, plenty of people here to help you. You can clear your doubts by asking questions. But, remember you should tried at-least once before asking questions in programming. All the best to your project.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38516587/how-to-use-selected-values-of-spinner-and-number-picker-for-if-else-statements can u help with this sir