# how to use selected values of spinner and number picker for if else statements

Tags: android

i want to use values of number picker and spinner together in a way that after selecting value of spinner and then number picker user enters search and this will stat another activity which has a list view i want to show selective items  of list according to selected values

```
package myfyp.pkg.futureadvisor;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.NumberPicker;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Enter_Info_Activity extends Activity {
       TextView t1,t2,t3;
       EditText e1,e2;
       Button b1;
       private Spinner spinner2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.enterinfor);
        t1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        t2=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.programe);
        e1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        t3=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.percentage);
        addItemsOnSpinner2();
        NumberPicker np = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.np);
        np.setMinValue(0);
        //Specify the maximum value/number of NumberPicker
        np.setMaxValue(100);
        //Gets whether the selector wheel wraps when reaching the min/max value.
        np.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);

        //Set a value change listener for NumberPicker


        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.search);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intenet=new Intent(v.getContext(),List_item.class);
                startActivityForResult(intenet,0);  
            }
        });



    }
     public void addItemsOnSpinner2() {

            spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            list.add("Bachelor of Architecture");
            list.add("Bachelor of Business Administration");
            list.add("Bachelor of Commerce");
            list.add("Bachelor of Computer Information Systems");
            list.add("Bachelor of Science in Construction Technology");
            list.add("Bachelor of Criminal Justice");
            list.add("Bachelor of Economics");
            list.add("Bachelor of Education");
            list.add("Bachelor of Engineering");
            list.add("Bachelor of Fine Arts");
            list.add("Bachelor of Information Systems");
            list.add("Bachelor of Social Work");
            list.add("Bachelor of Technology");
            list.add("Bachelor of Accountancy");
            list.add("Bachelor of Science in Aerospace Engineering");
            list.add("Bachelor of Science in Architecture");
            list.add("Bachelor of Science in Architectural Engineering");
            list.add("Bachelor of Science in Business Administration");
            list.add("Bachelor of Science in Business and Technology");
            list.add("Bachelor of Science in Chemical Engineering");
            list.add("Bachelor of Science in Chemistry");
            list.add("Bachelor of Science in Civil Engineering");
            list.add("Bachelor of Science in Computer Engineering");
            list.add("Bachelor of Science in Computer Science");
            list.add("Bachelor of Science in Criminal Justice");
            list.add("Bachelor of Science in Electrical Engineering");
            list.add("Bachelor of Science in Engineering Technology");
            list.add("Bachelor of Science in English Literature");
            list.add("Bachelor of Science in Environmental Science");
            list.add("Bachelor of Science in History");
            list.add("Bachelor of Science in Human Resources Management");
            list.add("Bachelor of Science in Industrial Engineering");
            list.add("Bachelor of Science in Information Technology");
            list.add("Bachelor of Science in Information Systems");
            list.add("Bachelor of Science in Information Systems");
            list.add("Bachelor of Science in Integrated Science");
            list.add("Bachelor of Science in Integrated Science");
            list.add("Bachelor of Science in International Relations");
            list.add("Bachelor of Science in Journalism");
            list.add("Bachelor of Science in Manufacturing Engineering");
            list.add("Bachelor of Science in Marketing");
            list.add("Bachelor of Science in Mathematics");
            list.add("Bachelor of Science in Mechanical Engineering");
            list.add("Bachelor of Science in Mining Engineering");
            list.add("Bachelor of Science in Software Engineering");
            list.add("Bachelor of Science in Physics");
            list.add("Bachelor of Science in Politics");
            list.add("Bachelor of Science in Psychology");
            list.add("Bachelor of Science in Real-Time Interactive Simulation");
            list.add("Bachelor of Science in Religion");
            list.add("Bachelor of Science in Risk Management and Insurance");
            list.add("Bachelor of Science in Science Education");
            list.add("Bachelor of Science in Systems Engineering");
            list.add("Bachelor of Science in Veterinary Technology");

            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
            dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinner2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
          }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_activity1, menu);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.aboutusid) {
            Intent aboutusintent = new Intent(this,Aboutus_Activity.class); 
            startActivity(aboutusintent);
            return true;
        }
        else if (id == R.id.helpid) {
            Intent helpIntent = new Intent(this,Help_Activity.class); 
            startActivity(helpIntent);
            return true;
        }
        else if (id == R.id.homeid) {
            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class); 
            startActivity(mainIntent);
            return true;}
        else if (id == R.id.exitid) {

            finish();
            System.exit(0);

        }

        else if (id == R.id.exitid) {

            return false;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you looking to just pass the values selected in the `Spinner` and `NumberPicker` to a new `Activity`?

Comment: I want to read values from number picker and spinner the i want to use them in if else statement according to selection for example                           if(numberpickervalue == some && spinnervale==some)                                show item 1 3 4 5 etc of listview

Comment: i have a listview which have almost 30 items but i want to chose some of them according to selection of user for numberpicker and spinner

Comment: That seems overly complicated, and is probably unnecessary. I doubt you want to write an `if` statement for each of the 3,000 possible combinations you can have... Give a better example of what you are looking to provide. What information are you looking to display based on the values selected?

Comment: its list of universities which i am gona display after user selection of degree programme and percentage it will only include 6 to 5 else-if statements

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are looking for how to pass data between activities. First, you will have to make your `NumberPicker` global:

```
private Spinner mSpinner;
private NumberPicker mNumberPicker;
```

With this in mind, you can send your data to a new `Activity` with an `Intent` like so:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContent(), ListItem.class);
intent.putExtra(ListItemActivity.EXTRA_MAJOR, mSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
intent.putExtra(ListItemActivity.EXTRA_INT, mNumberPicker.getValue());
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Then you can receive the data in your new `Activity` with `getIntent()`:

```
public class ListItemActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String EXTRA_MAJOR = "list_item:major";
    public static final String EXTRA_INT = "list_item:int";

    private int mInteger;
    private String mMajor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_item);

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        mMajor = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_MAJOR);
        mInteger = intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_INT);
    }

}
```